# How to solve View Encapsulation issue in Angular8?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have parent component and child component. Child component created as a modal component. So i have included child component selector inside parent component and i have set view encapsulation is none so that it will take parent component css and all and it's working also but parent component has #paper id applying some third party(rappidjs) libary css(for SVG diagramming). Same like child component has #dataMapper id. but here the thirdparty css is not taking because child component set to `'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None'`. If i will remove `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` it's working but modal is not working.  all the modals loading instead of onclick. How to solve this issue please advice me someone.

Coding:

**Parent Component TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-model',
  templateUrl: './data-model.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-model.component.css']
})

export class DataModelComponent implements OnInit{

// Modal

openModal(id: string) {
  this.modalApp = true;
  this.modalService.open(id);
}

closeModal(id: string) {
  this.modalService.close(id);
}
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <div class="tool-bar-section">
    <button class="btn" (click)="openModal('custom-modal-1');"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" style="font-size: 24px"></i></button>     
    </div>   
</div>
<div id="paper"> </div> ( this dom taking thirdparty css)

<app-modal id="custom-modal-1">           
    <h1 class="head-bar">Data Model - Import Excel  <a href="#" class="close-icon" (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-1');"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h1>
    <div class="modal-content-section">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#" (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-1');openModal('custom-modal-2');">Create New Schema</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-1');openModal('custom-modal-3');">Import Data to existing schema</a></li>
     </ul>       
    </div>        
</app-modal>
<app-modal id="custom-modal-2">       
    <h1 class="head-bar">Data Model - Import Excel  <a href="#" class="close-icon" (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-2');"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h1>
    <div class="modal-content-section">
        <div id="dataMapper"></div>       ( this dom is not taking thirdparty css)
        <p><a href="#" (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-2');openModal('custom-modal-4');">Data Mapping</a></p>
    </div>
</app-modal>
```

**Child Component HTML**

```
<div class="app-modal">
    <div class="app-modal-body">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="app-modal-background"></div>
```

**Child Component Ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() id: string;
  private element: any;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService, private el: ElementRef) {
      this.element = el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      // ensure id attribute exists
      if (!this.id) {
          console.error('modal must have an id');
          return;
      }

      // move element to bottom of page (just before </body>) so it can be displayed above everything else
      document.body.appendChild(this.element);

      // close modal on background click
      this.element.addEventListener('click', el => {
          if (el.target.className === 'app-modal') {
              this.close();
          }
      });

      // add self (this modal instance) to the modal service so it's accessible from controllers
      this.modalService.add(this);
  }

  // remove self from modal service when component is destroyed
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.modalService.remove(this.id);
      this.element.remove();
  }

  // open modal
  open(): void {
      this.element.style.display = 'block';
      document.body.classList.add('app-modal-open');
  }

  // close modal
  close(): void {
      this.element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.classList.remove('app-modal-open');
  }

}
```

**Modal Service Code**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

  private modals: any[] = [];

  add(modal: any) {
      // add modal to array of active modals
      this.modals.push(modal);
  }

  remove(id: string) {
      // remove modal from array of active modals
      this.modals = this.modals.filter(x => x.id !== id);
  }

  open(id: string) {
      // open modal specified by id
      const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === id);
      modal.open();
  }

  close(id: string) {
      // close modal specified by id
      const modal = this.modals.find(x => x.id === id);
      modal.close();
  }
}
```

Please let me know if more details required.

Comment: Try adding a stackblitz example rather than posting a bunch of code.

Comment: @AkhilAravind - Adding stackblitiz might take more time. becuase it's large app and i have placed the code only where the issue.

Comment: We dont need the full bunch of code block, just a minimal sample to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AkhilAravind - Ok let me create it. before that i just wanted to know is there any solution to apply and check it.

Comment: what you mean by `but parent component has some third party libary css(for SVG ).`

Comment: @AkhilAravind - Can you please check it now i have updated  the content. please let me know if any details required

Comment: How are you opening your modal? your `modalService` code?

Comment: If you are using `Angular`, you can use `*ngIf` to show your modal, instead of loading all modals in DOM

Comment: @Kenny - Modal Service Code added. Please check it now. I can use *ngIf but while loading the page #dataMapper id required to be loaded.

Comment: ViewEncapsulation.None means that CSS for that component becomes global, it doesn't mean that you will encapsulate your component to ignore third party CSS.

Comment: If you want to write `CSS` in parent component `CSS` and affect children's components, you should put `ViewEncapsulation.None` to parent component not to child component

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic - yes it's become global. but inside child component there is #dataMapper id. This id should take thirdparty css which is not taking properly. it's rendering wrong. third party css coming from 'src/assets/rappid.min.css'.

Comment: @DusanRadovanovic - Anything i have to change it root level to take that css proper.

Comment: @Kenny - Can you please advice to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you post some examples of the css that is supposed to be applied and the selectors? it's unclear what's going wrong here.  If this third party css is based on id's, that is very problematic if these ID's appear multiple times on the page, as in if these components are reused anywhere. only the first instance of an id will take the styles

Comment: It would be helpful for all of us to resolve your issue if you can create a minimal reproducible issue in stackblitz. Don't include your entire project, just the part where you are encountering this issue.

Comment: Added an answer with different approach but same result as it is we are not able to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Because of your modal.**
The modal is created on **top** of your app, (out of body tag if you look for the **modal wrapper** by inspecting it.)

**It is the Modal cause the dom structure not in sync with ng component structure**

So why the modal works with ng `Encapsulation`? Because your modal service can handle it.

But the 3rd party CSS file is not a part of your angular compile config (i.e. only sass, scss works). So it does ignore any `.css` even you import it properly.

To solve it, you can apply the .css globally. Or if you are afraid of that may **overwriting** other global styles, you can rename the css file to '_somefile.scss' (pay attention to the dash '_', it is important.)

Then under your project global style.scss file > create a selector matches your modal wrapper > under the selector: add a line that @import somefile (don't add extension)

*style.scss*

```
.modal-wrapper {
    @import somepath/somefile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described by you in problem that you want to inherit the css of parent compoenent inside the children component. So, i am assuming you are having same HTML elements in parent and children components and you don't want to duplicate your css.

As we are not able to replicate your issue and you have not created any stackblitz instance. I would suggest a better alternative which will work. Please find it below:

We can specify multiple CSS URL's inside the `styleUrls` property of `@Component` decorator metadata object. So, i would suggest you to pass the parent style file Url as well.

I have created a basic stackblitz showing where i am accessing CSS of parent component:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhewzy

Parent component css file (app.component.css)
 - I am specifying background color of `p` tag inside parent should be yellow. I want to inherit this in child component.

```
p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Below is child component CSS (hello.component.css)

```
p {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

As you want to use parent component inside the child component just use the style URL path in styleUrls property

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<p>I am child</p>`,
  styleUrls: [`./hello.component.css`, './app.component.css'],
})


export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

I hope it will help you.